# Most common grails plugins

Tags: grails

One of the features which makes Grails wonderful is the plugin architecture. Over the years, it has fostered a large community of developers and users that are continuously enhancing the value which Grails provides. I hardly ever find myself working on a project which doesn't have a handful of 3rd party and/or custom plugins.

What are some of your "go to" plugins? (e.g. the plugins which you find yourself almost always adding to your projects) What makes those plugins soo useful?

Comment: Isn't this question too open ended and need to be flaged or marked as CW?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say in my case:

1. [Database migration](http://www.grails.org/plugin/database-migration) to have more control of how the database is created/updated, etc.
2. [Spring Security](http://www.grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core) for authentication and authorization
3. [JQuery](http://www.grails.org/plugin/jquery) and [JQuery UI](http://grails.org/plugin/jquery-ui) because JQuery rocks
4. [Spring Cache](http://www.grails.org/plugin/springcache) to manage page caching
5. [Joda-time](http://grails.org/plugin/joda-time) to handle dates more easily
6. [Codenarc](http://grails.org/plugin/codenarc) to help keep coding standards and coding rules

There are other that I think are great but they depend more on your needs like:

- Searchable
- Rest
- jms
- Datasources

Answer (score 3):

My list comprise of:

1. [SpringSecurity](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/) for authentication & authorization
2. [Quartz](http://www.grails.org/plugin/quartz) for doing scheduled jobs.
3. [Mail plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/mail)
4. [Searchable](http://www.grails.org/plugin/searchable) is also noticable, though in most of the time I feel it doesn't take much to write the searching part myself.

Above non-default plugins saved me lots of time coding. For the rest, I think you could go and take a look at [here](http://www.grails.org/plugin/category/popular).

Answer (score 2):

[bean-fields](http://grails.org/plugin/bean-fields) is great for making your forms DRYer and allowing you to define the layout of your forms in one place.

Answer (score 2):

I like the [spring-security-*](http://www.grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core) family of plugins. Writing authentication and authorization code was always the least favourite part of creating websites for me.

Answer (score 1):

Spring-security Plugin

jasper Plugin

Rich-ui Plugin

Searchable Plugin

Export Plugin

Answer (score 1):

The spring security plugin for sure and the [AuditLogging](http://www.grails.org/plugin/audit-logging) plugin.

Answer (score 1):

- Spring-security-core for authentication
- remote-pagination for paginate with ajax on divs
- jasper for reports
- jquery and jquery-ui
- Quartz for scheduling jobs
- Searchable for searching capabilities

Answer (score 1):

In addition, I recommend  **[JQGrid](http://grails.org/plugin/jqgrid)** plugin for table manipulation.It's easy to use and has many futures like sorting, paging,crud operations ,json support, etc.